# which chart library is suit for popup different chart?

Tags: bar-chart, data-visualization, linechart

> The requirement is "on clicking on each data point of line chart the
>   another bar chart 
>       should open as a popup with detailed information".
>       We are using chart.js. Guide me which chart library is good for this functionality?

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
var activePoints = myLineChart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [d3.js.](http://d3js.org/) It's pretty low-level but very customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is ZingChart. [Here's a demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/J67SVMEY) that uses the ZingChart API and jQuery UI to pop up a modal with a new bar chart when you click on a line node.

If you have any questions about implementation, don't hesitate to reach out! I'm part of the ZingChart team.